# Trouble installing SQL Server Management Studio Express

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssms, sql-server-2008

Using VirtualBox I am running 64 bit versions of ...

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Express
- SharePoint Foundation

I want to install SQL Server Management Studio Express, but I get this warning:

> "This program has known compatibility issues."

I would rather not screw up this VM. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention which version or architecture of SSMS you're tying to install.  Perhaps you can update your question to indicate this.

The 64 bit SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 is [available here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx) -- you can also download SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with the management tools bundled in the installer.  This version installs and runs, without issue, on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: The installer the link you provided worked. The installer from this link http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b failed.

Comment: @mmcglynn Your comment's link is the SQL 2008 (not R2) version.  This version will *work* on Windows Server 2008 R2, but you should install the latest [SQL 2008 Express service pack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968382) to ensure compatibility issues are resolved.